# How to make a non-UI countdown in Unity?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a countdown attached to a sprite. The countdown will count down from 10 to zero, and won't be attached to the Canvas, so it won't be static on the screen. All of the tutorials for something like this have been for UI and don't allow 3D text. Anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

1. Use UI elements on a separate canvas set to World Space
2. Use the TextMesh element to put a 3D mesh of text in the world

I don't really know the pros and cons of each approach so go with whichever is easier for you to implement and keep the other in mind if you run into problems.

If you're looking for a detailed tutorial, anything explaining how to do popup damage numbers will be the same method, just with a different script telling it what text to display. There are a few good tutorials on the [top of the YouTube results](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=unity%20damage%20numbers).

As for the countdown script, it's fairly simple.

```
//put this script on a GameObject prefab with a TextMesh component, or a canvas element
public class Countdown : MonoBehaviour
{

public TextMesh textComponent; //set this in inspector
public float time;  //This can be set in inspector for this prefab
float timeLeft;
public void OnEnable()
{
    textComponent = GetComponent<TextMesh>();  //in case you forget to set the inspector
    timeLeft = time;
}
private void Update()
{
    timeLeft -= Time.deltaTime;  //subtract how much time passed last frame
    textComponent.text = Mathf.CeilToInt(timeLeft).ToString();  //only show full seconds
    if(timeLeft < 0) { gameObject.SetActive(false); }  //disable this entire gameobject
}
}
```